# Clojure: anonymous function with reduce

Tags: clojure

I am new to clojure and have noticed this example at clojure docs.

`(reduce (fn [m [k v]] (assoc m v k)) {}{:b 2 :a 1 :c 3})`

**Output:** `;;=> {2 :b, 1 :a, 3 :c}`

Can anybody explain behind logic of the code?

Comment: What do you think it means? What parts are you having trouble with?

Comment: `{}{:b 2 :a 1 :c 3}`

Comment: @user1702169 having those two maps "glued" together like this does not really help here (unless you are code golfing). Write it as `{} {...}` and it will be clear, that those are two separate things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reduce` applies a function to an accumulator and each element in a sequence, building a final result. ClojureDocs gives [the signature for reduce](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) as either `(reduce f coll)` or `(reduce f val coll)`. Your example has the latter signature with elements matching as follows:

- `f` : The function to apply to each entry, `(fn [m [k v]] ...`
- `val` : The initial accumulator, `{}`
- `coll` : The collection to operate on, `{:b 2 :a 1 :c 3}`

Note that there is no delimiter (i.e., space) between the second and the third parameter of your reduce call. Clojure does not require one.

Then, looking at the inner anonymous function: `(fn [m [k v]] (assoc m v k))`. The first argument `m` is the current value of accumulator, which was `{}` at the start of the reduce. [Destructuring syntax](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) is used for the second argument, which is the current value to be prosessed, that is, a map entry. The map entry is destructured to its key `k` and value `v`. The body of the anonymous function simply puts a new "reversed" entry to the accumulator (i.e., map), so that the value of the original sequence `v` is the key, and the key `k` becomes the value. The result is similar to applying the Clojure API function [map-invert](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/map-invert).

Note that there is a separate [reduce-kv](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce-kv) function for reducing associative collections (e.g., a map). `reduce-kv` "does the destructuring for you". This allows the anonymous function to be written as:

```
(fn [m k v] (assoc m v k))
```

Or even more simply with the short notation:

```
#(assoc %1 %3 %2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first map, which is empty, is an optional initializing value and it is the first argument passed to the reducing function. The second map is the collection whose items are to be reduced. In this case, each item is a `MapEntry`, and they are passed as the second argument to the reducing function one at a time.

Given that your input map has three key/value pairs, the reducing function will be called three times. The reducing function's `m` argument refers to the initializing value (empty map) on the first invocation and the *decomposed* second argument `k and v` come from the `MapEntry` pair being passed in the iteration.

While most times the reducing function returns the first argument once it has been operated on, in you example it reverses the key/value of the second argument and associates the new pair to the initializing value, it is not strictly required to do so..

Answer (score 0):

It means `reduce` the map `{:b 2 :a 1 :c 3}` with function `(fn [m [k v]] (assoc m v k))` which sequentially take a key-value pair `[k v]` from the map and associate it with accumulator hash-map `m`. Initial state of accumulator hash-map is set to be empty (`{}`).